Adding key value pair into dictionary by looping through a list without using the foreach loop
I have the code as below, how can I avoid using foreach below, I am looping through a list and adding key value into a Dictionary, is there anyway I can avoid the foreach loop in the below code and add values to the Dictionary
DataQueryResult<Agreement> _agreements = new DataQueryResult<Agreement>();
Dictionary<Guid, Contact> _contacts = new Dictionary<Guid, Contact>();
_agreements = this.agreementRepository.GetAgreementsByQuery(_parameters);
Agreement _agreement = _agreements?.Data?.FirstOrDefault();

if (_agreement.AgreementActive)
{
    // add contactids for the agreemenet
    var _agreementContacts = await this.contactRepository.GetAgreementContactsAsync(_agreement.AgreementId.Value, null);
     
    foreach (var _contact in _agreementContacts.Data)
    {         
        if (_contact.Role.RoleId == DCCommonConstants.RoleId.KeyPersonnel &&
            _contact.PersonActive &&
            !_contacts.ContainsKey(_contact.ContactId.Value))
        {
            _contacts.Add(_contact.ContactId.Value, _contact);
        }
    }
}  

Any help would be appreciated greatly, thanks in advance.

Linq Groupby then ToDictionary ... but linq just abstracts you from the foreach... what is the reason for wanting to avoid foreach?

Dictionary doesn't have .AddRange, because it could fail part way with a duplicate key. Which makes it hard to define what the correct behaviour should be on failure. So you can either .ToDictionary or .Add / [key]= each element.

What version of .NET are you running? If a newer version, you can remove the ContainsKey and just use TryAdd.

Consider moving the _contact.Role.RoleId == DCCommonConstants.RoleId.KeyPersonnel &&             _contact.PersonActive filter inside of GetAgreementContactsAsync. Databases are very good at filtering.

Why do you want to avoid using foreach?

You don't write why you want to do this, but something like the following should do the trick:
var contacts = _agreementContacts.Data
    .Where(c => c.Role.RoleId == DCCommonConstants.RoleId.KeyPersonnel &&
                c.PersonActive)
    .GroupBy(c => c.ContactId.Value)
    .ToDictionary(c => c.First().ContactId.Value, _contact => _contact);

As I read the GroupBy documentation, the elements in the group preserve the original ordering, so taking the First() of those should be equivalent to checking whether the key is already in the dictionary.

thank you my friend, I have a lead who never want to use for loops,

@Abdul FWIW, that's not really an explanation. Why doesn't the lead want to use for loops?
